# Remove whitespace around progress element inside a form

Tags: html, css

How do I remove the space shown as green ?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJ7k4.jpg

I am unable to ascertain if the space is due to the form or its parent div which is an inline-grid ?

Here is my attempt : https://codepen.io/bynge/pen/movmdY

```
.form-group {border: thin #d9d9d9  ;min-width: 100px;margin: 0;font: 0;width:100%}
.form-group {align-items: baseline; background:green;}
.form-inputLabel input{ width: 0.1px;
    height: 0.1px;
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
}
.form-inputLabel {display:block;font-size: 1em;color: white;background-color: grey;
text-align:center;cursor: pointer;margin:0;padding:0;}
.form-inputLabel:focus,
.form-inputLabel:hover {background-color: red;}
```

I want no space between the children inside an uploadTableGuide, which means no green colors in codepen example.

Comment: if I may, actually I can't see *space* between the `table-upload-guide` and the `form-group` inside the `uploadTableGuide` - your codepen & image do not look the same... could you pls clarify

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the _shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**_. See: How to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
progress{
    display: flex;
}
```

Whitespace was caused by progress tag. property flex on display will remove it. This should be told clearly somewhere in the docs about progress I wish.

Answer (score 1):

I kinda went through your code and made some changes, I'm not very good at this because I'm new to this so please bear with me. But I hope this helps you out in some way.

I removed this from the HTML code:

```
<progress value="0" max="100" class="uploadStatus"></progress>
```

And you don’t need this too (CSS):

```
.form-group {align-items: baseline; background:green;}
```

Comment: For the OP, and future users, to understand what you did,  and why, explain your answers. Posting a code w/o is pretty useless, even if it does solve an issue. And I do hope you _know_ the answer, or else your not helping, and could instead mislead the OP, which wouldn't be good.

Comment: Yes sir, Thanks for letting me know, I'm kinda new to this whole thing so I'm still learning, I'll try not to make the same mistakes again, Have a good one :)

Comment: Good, and the same goes for this answer. I recommend you edit it properly or delete it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Kindly replace you existing css class with mine and the issue is resolved

css
.form-group {
    position: relative;
    align-items: baseline;
    background: green;
}
progress{
    height: 3px;
    background-color: #291919;
    width: 100%;
    color: yellow;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9;
    left: 0;
    border-radius: 1px;
    margin-top: 0em;
    display: flex;
}
```

Comment: For the OP, and future users, to understand what you did,  and why, explain your answers. Posting a code w/o is pretty useless, even if it does solve an issue.